# Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'CSSResultArray'

Tags: lit-element

i installed polymer.js lit-element into my project. when i try to build the project it gives error: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'CSSResultArray'

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build lit-element yourself, we publish the compiled JS to npm.

If you must, then you need to use our tsconfig settings which include the "esnext.array" library.